# Video not playing continuously

Tags: qt, opencv

I am playing video in Qt using opencv. I am having 6 tiled view cameras from which I am playing video. The problem is if one of the videos is not playing i.e finishes then the GUI freezes and exits. The error I get is you must reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch the exceptions there. How to do this?
The code I am using is as follows.

Somewhere in a function

```
 void MainWindow::ActivateWindow()
{
  //Some part of code to set Index for stacked widget

   if(stackWidget->currentIndex()==9)
   {
      const int imagePeriod == 1000/25;
      imageTimer->setInterval(imagePeriod);
      connect(imageTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(demoSlot());
      imageTimer->start();
   }
}
```

In slot demoSlot

```
 void MainWindow::demoSlot()
{
   captureCamera1 cvCaptureFromFile("/root/mp.mp4");
   captureCamera2 cvCaptureFromFile("/root/mp.mp4");
   captureCamera3 cvCaptureFromFile("/root/mp.mp4");

   while(imageTimer->isActive())
   {
      frameCamera1 = cvQueryFrame(captureCamera1);
      frameCamera2 = cvQueryFrame(captureCamera2);
      frameCamera3 = cvQueryFrame(captureCamera2);

      sourceImageCam1 = frameCamera1;
      sourceImageCam2 = frameCamera2;
      sourceImageCam3 = frameCamera3;

      cv::resize(sourceImageCam1,sourceImageCam1,cv::size(400,100),0,0);
      cv::resize(sourceImageCam1,sourceImageCam1,cv::size(400,100),0,0);
      cv::resize(sourceImageCam1,sourceImageCam1,cv::size(400,100),0,0);

      cv::cvtColor(sourceImageCam1,sourceImageCam2,CV_BGR2RGB);
      cv::cvtColor(sourceImageCam2,sourceImageCam2,CV_BGR2RGB);
      cv::cvtColor(sourceImageCam2,sourceImageCam2,CV_BGR2RGB);

      QImage tempImage1 = QImage((const unsigned char* sourceImageCam1.data,sourceImageCam1.cols,sourceImageCam2.rows,QImage::Format_RG888);
      QImage tempImage2 = QImage((const unsigned char* sourceImageCam2.data,sourceImageCam2.cols,sourceImageCam2.rows,QImage::Format_RG888);
      QImage tempImage3 = QImage((const unsigned char* sourceImageCam3.data,sourceImageCam3.cols,sourceImageCam3.rows,QImage::Format_RG888);

      labelCameraCapture1->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(tempImage1));     //label to display video
      labelCameraCapture2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(tempImage2));
      labelCameraCapture3->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(tempImage3));

      lblCameraCapture1->resize(lblCameraCapture1->Pixmap->size());
      lblCameraCapture1->resize(lblCameraCapture1->Pixmap->size());
      lblCameraCapture1->resize(lblCameraCapture1->Pixmap->size());

      cvWaitkey(20);
      qApp->processEvents();
    }
 if(imageTimer->isActive())
 {
   imageTimer->stop();
 }
 else
 {
   imageTimer->start();
 }
}
```

In header file

```
   cvCapture *captureCamera1;
   cvCapture *captureCamera1;
   cvCapture *captureCamera1;

   IplImage frameCamera1;
   IplImage frameCamera2;
   IplImage frameCamera3;

   cv::Mat sourceImageCam1;
   cv::Mat sourceImageCam2;
   cv::Mat sourceImageCam3;
```

Comment: This slot `MainWindow::demoSlot()` is completely wrong on so many levels! WTF #1 `cvWaitkey(20);`, WTF #2 `while(imageTimer->isActive())`, WTF #3 `if(imageTimer->isActive()) ... stop()   ... start()`

Comment: Simply I don't see any useful code in this slot even a single line. It just blocks main thread. I suspect that you can trash everything except `//Code to play video` (assuming that you hid come code in this place) and this will work.

Comment: obviously I didnt write the entire code. I just wrote the part because of which I think the problem might be arising. Rest of the code is simply the part where we set the capture to a frame and resize and setPixmap. Is the main thread getting block due to the while loop? But if I remove the while loop the video doesn't play. It needs some condition to play the video. Do I have to put the entire video in a QThread and start and stop it as per need or is there any other solution?

Comment: show the code where you are playing video. The part of code you have show is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick changing that to 3 movies is simple.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
Q_OBJECT

   explicit QMainWindow(QWidget *parent) ....
   // prepare timer and so on

public slots:
   void startVideo() {
      vid1.close();
      vid1.open("/root/mp.mp4");
      imageTimer->start();
   }

   void demoSlot() {
      cv::Mat frame;
      vid1 >> frame;
      cv::cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_BGR2RGB);
      QImage img((uchar*) frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
      label1->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
   }

private:
   ...
   QTimer *imageTimer;
   cv::VideoCapture vid1;
};
```

Comment: When should I call the startVideo() slot?

Comment: let me guess: whenever you want to start playing video(s)

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I tried that way. In the place where I am setting my index I called startvideo and then the usual demoSlot thing. The program is getting unexpectedly finished and the other problem is it is saying there is nothing like vid1.close. However there is vid1.open.

Comment: I wrote this from memory, to close video there is `release` function. The pattern how to play video with openCv is more important here, details I'm leaving for you.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try if this solves the problem I will up the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if frame captured from camera is NULL. Then simply skip processing steps for this camera.

And it'll be better to not mix C++ and C interfaces (I mean cv::Mat and IplImage).